# Why do lt and gt in Perl not work for comparing real numbers?

Tags: perl

Lets examine the following perl code

```
if ($a lt 0.00 or $a gt 100.000)
{
    print "a must be between 0 and 100 \n";
    exit 1
}
exit 0
```

Lets say a equals 5. The above code will exit with failure status because a isn't between 0 and 100.

Simply replacing the `lt` and `gt` with the actual operators they represent, `<` and `>` respectively, yields the expected results. Replacing the 100 with a number starting with a 9 will also yield the expected result.

Why are Perl's comparison operators telling me 5 is not between 0 and 100?

Comment: edited title, since 'the expected results' is only your expectation, which was wrong.

Comment: You might be confused by the `test` command (used in shell scripts as `[` ... `]`), which uses `-gt` and `-lt` for numeric comparisons.

Comment: It's also bad new to use `$a`. Aside from single character variable names just being bad in general, it's also got a specific meaning in `perl` - it's used for `sort`.

Answer (score 12):

`lt` and `gt` are string operators, with numbers you want to use plain old `<` and `>`. Perl is polymorphic on values, so it's monomorphic on operators (unlike for example python which is the other way around).

Comment: An easy way to remember it is that all the operators whose names are spelled in letters (`eq`, `lt`, `cmp` etc...) operate on strings, while the operators whose names look like maths symbols (`==`, `<`, `<=>`, etc...) operate on numbers.

Answer (score 6):

In perl the `lt` and `gt` operators are not the same as the `<` and `>`. the perl documentation details this here [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) under rational operators, below is extracted from the documentation:

```
Binary "<" returns true if the left argument is numerically less than the right argument.
Binary ">" returns true if the left argument is numerically greater than the right argument.
Binary "<=" returns true if the left argument is numerically less than or equal to the right argument.
Binary ">=" returns true if the left argument is numerically greater than or equal to the right argument.
Binary "lt" returns true if the left argument is stringwise less than the right argument.
Binary "gt" returns true if the left argument is stringwise greater than the right argument.
Binary "le" returns true if the left argument is stringwise less than or equal to the right argument.
Binary "ge" returns true if the left argument is stringwise greater than or equal to the right argument.
```

Since perl does not have a string object and integer object perl has to make a guess at the context of the object. The only way perl can know if you you are comparing a string or an integer is by ensuring that the rational operators for `lt` and `gt` force the context for comparisons as a sting and that `<` and `>` operators for the context for comparisons as integers